# Problema com a referência do serviço (wcf) no Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2015

Estou utilizando VS2015 (framework 4.6) em uma solution com dois projetos, um projeto é de wcf (rodando no IIS) e o outro projeto é uma aplicação web. Adicionei o meu serviço (wcf) na minha aplicação web normalmente, mas ao tentar instanciá-lo, notei que o serviço não estava aparecendo no intellisense. Verifiquei a referência do serviço e percebi que ele não esta sendo gerado "adequadamente", notei também que no webconfig da aplicação não esta apresentando o endpoint do serviço adicionado. Realizei um teste utilizando um serviço hospedado em um servidor (wcf + windows server 2012) e consegui instancia-lo e consumi-lo sem nenhum problema.
O problema só ocorre na referencia do serviço, pois ao executa-lo diretamente (wcfclient ou soapui) o serviço funciona corretamente.

obs:  estou usando windows 10 + IIS8

Alguém já teve este problema ? Seria alguma configuração que devo realizar no win10 ? framework?

Comment: Conseguiu alguma solução para o problema? Estou com um bem parecido e pode encontrar aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89192/wcf-para-consumo-em-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-silverlight-windows-phone-8-0