# WCF para consumo em aplicação Silverlight (Windows Phone 8.0)

Tags: c#, windows-phone, wcf, windows-phone-8-1, silverlight

Estou com problema ao adicionar a ServiceReference, ele adiciona normalmente porém quando vai gerar a classe "Client" ele encontra o seguinte erro:

> No endpoints compatible with Silverlight 3 were found. The generated
>   client class will not be usable unless endpoint information is
>   provided via the constructor.

Na criação do .svc eu selecionei o novo item com compatibilidade para o Silverlight. Já tentei também alterar o projeto windows phone para a versão 8.1 Silverlight mas também sem sucesso. Li em alguns tutoriais que isso poderia ser um bug do VS, mas também que já havia sido corrigido (ou seja, posso estar com a versão de alguma coisa desatualizada, mas estou com o VS2015).

Ao inserir um novo .svc e executando ele vazio, funciona de cara, o problema começa a surgir quando eu insiro métodos que retornam do tipo ***List<>***, o mais estranho é que na primeira vez que criei um projeto WCF eu fiz o mesmo processo e funcionou de cara, tentei inserir este projeto (o que funcionava) na solution e ele também não funcionou neste caso.

***.SVC***:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class CargaInicial : ICargaInicial
    {
        LojaService _lojaService = new LojaService();
        UsuarioService _usuarioService = new UsuarioService();
        ProdutoService _produtoService = new ProdutoService();

        public Loja ObterLoja()
        {
            return _lojaService.ObterLoja();
        }

        public List<Usuario> ObterUsuarios()
        {
            return this._usuarioService.ObterUsuarios();
        }

        public List<Produto> ObterProdutos()
        {
            return _produtoService.ObterTodosProdutos();
        }
    }
```

***Interface***:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CargaInicial : ICargaInicial
{
    LojaService _lojaService = new LojaService();
    UsuarioService _usuarioService = new UsuarioService();
    ProdutoService _produtoService = new ProdutoService();

    public Loja ObterLoja()
    {
        return _lojaService.ObterLoja();
    }
    public List<Usuario> ObterUsuarios()
    {
        return this._usuarioService.ObterUsuarios();
    }

    public List<Produto> ObterProdutos()
    {
        return _produtoService.ObterTodosProdutos();
    }
}
```

***Ao inserir a referencia eu usei as seguintes configurações***:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Classe Produto***:

```
[Table("Produto")]
public class Produto : Entity<Guid>, IProduto
{
    [Required]
    public string Codigo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal PrecoVenda { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DataHoraUltimaAtualizacao { get; set; }
}
```

Esta classe é de outro projeto na mesma solution. Já tentei inserir o ***[DataContract]*** e ***[DataMemberContract]*** mas ainda assim não obtive sucesso.

Talvez uma solução seja alterar a versão do ***Silverlight*** no projeto, mas não sei como fazer isso e também tenho que usar a versão 8.0 pois é um requisito.

Answer (score 1):

Sempre que eu consumo um serviço, nunca consegui colocar a referencia no Windows Phone e funcionar de sem problemas.

Agora eu sempre uso o RestSharp para consumir qualquer serviço (WCF, ASMX, WebAPI, etc). Funciona muito bem e não precisa incluir a referência do serviço.

Exemplo:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
// client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

// easily add HTTP Headers
request.AddHeader("header", "value");

// add files to upload (works with compatible verbs)
request.AddFile(path);

// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

// or automatically deserialize result
// return content type is sniffed but can be explicitly set via RestClient.AddHandler();
RestResponse<Person> response2 = client.Execute<Person>(request);
var name = response2.Data.Name;

// easy async support
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
});
```

Referência: http://restsharp.org/

Abraços.